# sticky navigation jumps with css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to build sticky navigation but the problem is that when the scrollTop reaches 300px my navigation is jumping too fast and I want to scroll it smoothly and I am not sure where the problem is ( why the navigation is jumping out(bouncing) ).

https://jsfiddle.net/7mgLkk53/1/

```
jsfiddle
```

Comment: link is broken and show what you have tried?

Comment: sorry for that, link is fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css3 transition property to make it smoother on class `.main-head-scrolled`

[**Fiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/7mgLkk53/2/)

Answer (score 0):

change your scrollTop pixel logic if its more that 0 then add "main-head-scrolled" class

```
$(this).scrollTop() > 0
```

here is a working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/7mgLkk53/3/

Comment: okey but when i change it let's say $(this).scrollTop() > 300 and when 300px are reached navigation is showing up again with this ugly jumping / bouncing effects